# RxSwift PublishSubject is being disposed

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I bind Button pressed to `PublishSubject` in a router like so:

```
hambugerButton
   .rx_tap
   .bindTo(router.openMenu)
   .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

In my Router:

```
let openMenu = PublishSubject<Void>()
//...
openMenu
   .map { _ in
       menuNavigationController
    }
    .bindTo(mainNavigationController.rx_present())
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

However, when the controller is being deallocated, the button is sending 'complete' signal. When `PublishSubject` receives it, it won't react to signals from another controller (which is understandable: it is an `Observable` guarantee).

The only solution I came up with:

```
hambugerButton
    .rx_tap
    .subscribeNext {
        self.router.openMenu.onNext()
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Which looks ugly and kinda spoils the idea of a reactive interface.
My question is, is there a way to avoid propagation of the `Completed` event to `PublishSubject`? Can I make some `Observer` which will ignore such events?

Answer (score 0):

If the view controller which owns the `hamburgerButton` is being deallocated, and thus the `hamburgerButton` is also being deallocated, why wouldn't you want the binding to `router.openMenu` to also be deallocated?  Maybe it's not clear what your view controller hierarchy is from your question.

Also, in the first snippet, you shouldn't be making a binding without adding it to a `DisposeBag` like so:

```
hambugerButton
   .rx_tap
   .bindTo(router.openMenu)
   .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks I just didn't copy disposeBag.
I don't want it to be deallocated because Router is a global object and another controller could/would/is bind to it. Some refCount thing could be useful here.

Comment: I see what you're saying now.  That's a good question, I'm not sure of a better way to do it than just calling `onNext` as you already are.  I'm not aware of any way to squelch a `Completed` event, but now you've got me thinking ;) However, I think it begs the question of if you should be trying to in the first place. That, and singletons are often something to be avoided.